# Remove English - United States language from Firefox

Tags: firefox, language, dictionary

How do I remove the **English (United States)** dictionary from Firefox? It's not an add-on so I'm guessing it's built into Firefox by default. Maybe that makes it unremovable?

I noticed whilst typing a Hotmail email in Firefox that the default language seems to be English/United States. As I am from the UK I thought I would add in the English/United Kingdom dictionary, which I have.  This is now the default language and I don't need the US dictionary.

Firefox 3.6.2 on Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dictionaries are stored in the dictionaries folder in the Firefox program folder (C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\dictionaries) and you can remove the files from that folder.

The [Mozilla Add-ons Dictionaries page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/browse/type:3) is displayed. To add a dictionary to your Firefox installation, click the "Install Dictionary" link next to the dictionary you want to add. The Software Installation window appears. When it is displayed, click `Install Now`, which should open the Add-ons window, where you'll see the dictionary being installed.

[image]

To enable the dictionary, click the `Restart Firefox` button, in the Add-ons window. 
You can even see for more [here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Using%20the%20spell%20checker).

Comment: NB: this will be under Program Files x86 if you are running a 64 bit windows

Answer (score 7):

To remove the en-US dictionaries so that they are no longer accidentally triggered, and to ensure that your chosen dictionary is used at all times, do the following:

1. Shut down Firefox.
2. Go to your install directory (“Mozilla Firefox”, usually under “C:\Program Files” in XP).
3. Look for the “dictionaries” folder.
4. In that folder, you will find the files:

   - en-US.aff
   - en-US.dic
5. Delete or remove these two files out of the folder.
6. Restart Firefox.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. The problem is that unless you do this anything that non-US users type in a text box will randomly switch back to "English (United States)". It's ridiculous that you have to manually delete files to get basic functionality like language selection to work 24/7. The other problem is that I believe that these files regenerate every time there is a Firefox update (every 3 hours isn't it? {sardonic scowl}) since I know that I've deleted them before based on this answer so next time I find them I'm going to write a scheduled task to purge the accursed things.

Comment: Thanks will also make a scheduled task, I found my firefox keeps randomly switching back to the en-us dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note for the record, the above file location isn't always where the dictionaries are found.

I found them in `C:\Users\<My username>\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\dictionaries` presumably because it's a corporate computer.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, for OS X users, the default US dictionaries are found in `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/dictionaries`.

Comment: In firefox 34.0 and OS X 10.10.1 it seems that the defaults ones are here
`/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/dictionaries`